# spring security - access to images

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
<beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.mkyong.web.AuthSuccessHandler" />
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**"   access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
    <logout logout-success-url="/"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <!--<password-encoder hash="sha"></password-encoder> -->
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And I have mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>

    <bean
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>
   </beans>
```

I store my images in folder "/images/" . 
I want to display image in jsp . When I write

```
img src="/images/photo1"
```

in "/welcome" it works . But when I write it in "/user/" it doesn't work and return 403 error . How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Try to add <http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/> before <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">. Hope your user folder and image in same directory.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me